Flexbox two column in css
I have two columun in one section.
The first column in an image.
The second column is just text.
I want these to flex.
The problem is that, the image gets too small when I try to flex-wrap the content any ideas?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Flexbox with flex-wrap</title>
  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      gap: 1rem;
    }
    
    .d-column {
      flex: 2 1 200px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .img-container {
      flex: 1 0 200px;
      width: fit-container;
      border-raduis: 12px;
    }
    
    img {
      max-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      object-fit: cover;
      border-radius: 12px;
      aspect-ratio: 2/1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
      <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCLYgZkVCSbBRILyzR3yMNgiKunVGJ1LaWjZV-8Zy0H-LyGeNGedRizu0F_2bSq_Vsd85DnNveXZlqU7nH0tu4248W0jdu0NM0UBx9waE&usqp=CAc" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="d-column">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
      <p>This is the content of column 2.</p>
      <p>This content determines the height of column 1.</p>
      <p>This content can be as long as needed.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>




I tried flexing using the content it is not working

Read up on flex-basis.

Does this help:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Flexbox with flex-wrap</title>
<style>
    .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        gap: 1rem;
        align-items: stretch; 
    }

    .img-container {
        flex: 1 1 200px; 
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border-radius: 12px;
    }
  
    img {
        width: 100%; 
        height: auto; 
        object-fit: cover; 
        border-radius: 12px;
    }

    .d-column {
        flex: 2 1 300px; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="img-container">
        <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/shopping?q=tbn:ANd9GcSCLYgZkVCSbBRILyzR3yMNgiKunVGJ1LaWjZV-8Zy0H-LyGeNGedRizu0F_2bSq_Vsd85DnNveXZlqU7nH0tu4248W0jdu0NM0UBx9waE&usqp=CAc" alt="Image">
    </div>
    <div class="d-column">
        <h2>Column 2</h2>
        <p>This is the content of column 2. This content determines the height of column 1. This content can be as long as needed.</p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>



which gives


Found this to be optimal
.container {
    display: flex;
    gap: 1rem;
}
.img-container {
flex: 1 0 400px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
img {
    width: 100%; 
    height: auto; 
    object-fit: cover; 
    border-radius: 12px;
}
.d-column {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

